# OpenVZ bridged networked adapters won't work from sample configs

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvz

I've made a copy of the basic config and added the line:

```
NETIF="ifname=eth0,bridge=br0"
```

When I create a new machine and enter it I can't make the network adapter work yet creating an instance from the basic config (and same template os) and then applying:

```
vzctl set 101 --netif_add eth0,,,,br0 --save
```

This configuration works fine. I've checked the configs of any machines made with the first method and it seems to create the configs correctly yet this problem still persists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My setup for a bridged network guest is as follows:

```
NETIF="ifname=eth0,mac=00:18:51:D4:CC:53,host_ifname=veth103.0,host_mac=00:18:51:43:84:87"
```

veth103.0 is the device that shows up on the host, which is then added to the eth0 of the host as vmbr0, which is my bridge device.

Comment: yes, but that's for a instance config, I'm using a sample which I can then use to create new machines without running the netif_add command each time afterwards, I'd assume it I place any of the config it'll create the same host adapter to add to the bridge

Comment: @Sly - I was never able to get that feature to work. Keep trying though, it's been 1-1/2 to 2 years since I tried.

Comment: yeah seems it still is, it's odd because it creates the correct config it seems and then the adapters seem to be correctly set up, they bind anyways. It's purely when trying to do stuff like request a dhcp in the container it goes wrong

Comment: @Sly - that sounds like what I ran into as well. I gave up and did the above. Might be worth a ask on the openvz forums: http://forum.openvz.org/